# StartupScripts in InitialSessionState not invoked for PS Core RunspacePool

Tags: powershell

I am using a RunspacePool for getting a pre-initialized Runspace for a PS:

```
using (RunspacePool RsPool = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool(iss))
{
  RsPool.Open();
  using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
  {
```

My initial session state looks (simplified) like so:

```
var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;
iss.Variables.Add(new SessionStateVariableEntry("testVar", myVar, "no description"));
iss.StartupScripts.Add("some PS script here");
```

Variables are properly available (usable later in PS; importing modules also works). However, the startup script does not run. Is there something special about that? Because at least the source code https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/InitialSessionState.cs#L2558 implies that it should run.

This is running in a .NET Core 3.1 Console with the PS SDK NuGet installed. Manually creating a Runspace, invoking a command on its pipeline and then building a PS on top of it works fine. But I'd like to a have pool of pre-initialized Runspaces around.

EDIT

I added

```
defaultSessionState.ThrowOnRunspaceOpenError = true;
```

This now at least tells me that something went wrong:

```
The term 'some PS script here' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again..'
```

This happens even with a simple Import-Module "modulexyz". Is there specific syntax required here?

Comment: I have continued to read the PS Core code - https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/InitialSessionState.cs#L2864 this calling AddCommand with false for the isScript parameter really begs the question why it would be called StartupScripts (and how I would get scripts to run)

Comment: Have you tried specifying the path to a script?

Comment: Yes, via https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13812 I then tried passing a script path. The docs / error message definitely imply that I can pass verbatim scripts though.